# Vuejs - Cannot read property 'location' of undefined when loading API

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm having problems accessing values of my data objects in Vue, after loading the Google maps-api.

Data:

```
data() {
    return {
        lat : 0,
        long : 0,
        location: '46.414382,10.013988' 
    }
}
```

My method, that I call.

```
methods: {
    randomLocation: function(){
        this.lat = Math.random() * (90 + 90) - 90;
        this.long = Math.random() * (180 + 180) - 180;
        this.location = this.lat + ',' + this.long;
        console.log("Random location: ", this.location);

        GoogleMapsLoader.load(
            function(google) {
                var sv = new google.maps.StreetViewService();
                console.log(this.location);
            }
        );
    }
}
```

The console prints an error when I call `randomLocation`. It says it can't access `this.location` int `GoogleMapsLoader.load(...)`. Why is that and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to preserve the context:

```
GoogleMapsLoader.load((google) => {
  var sv = new google.maps.StreetViewService();
  console.log(this.location);
});
```

Comment: Keep in mind, es6 arrow functions aren't supported in IE11, but if you are using the typical Vue/Webpack setup with Babel, it will be transpiled to work.

Answer (score 1):

Because `GoogleMapsLoader.load()` runs in a context that is different from the context outside of it.

In other words, it changes what `this` points to. You can just cache a reference to the outer `this`:

```
randomLocation: function(){
    this.lat = Math.random() * (90 + 90) - 90;
    this.long = Math.random() * (180 + 180) - 180;
    this.location = this.lat + ',' + this.long;
    console.log("Random location: ", this.location);
    let outer_this = this; //<-- here

    GoogleMapsLoader.load(
        function(google)  {
        var sv = new google.maps.StreetViewService();
        console.log(outer_this.location); //<-- here

    });
},
```